# how to set loginPath in config file

Tags: redirect, login, redirection

I made a modal for login at homepage and put `{%requireLogin%}` tag in "User Profile" page.
My `general.php` file looks like below:

```
'dev' => [
        // Base site URL
        'siteUrl' => null,

        // Dev Mode (see https://craftcms.com/support/dev-mode)
        'devMode' => true,
        'loginPath' => '/',
    ],
```

I hope to prevent users to go to "User Profile" page without login and redirect them to homepage. But the issue is when I login on the homepage, the browser gives an error `redirected you too many times.`

Any idea how to do that please? Many thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

OK, no one answered....I have to take another way to do which is to put a piece of code like this into user-profile page

```
{% if not currentUser %}
  {% redirect '/' %}
{% endif %}
```

and take out `loginPath` setting in config file.

Comment: Do you have a requireLogin tag on the homepage - the template behind the url you are routing to? What redirecting to the / does is redirect to the homepage. If you have a requireLogin tag on this page your routing will go haywire in an infinite loop.

Comment: @GįëłTėttëłæår no, it doesn't make any sense to make homepage login-required. And that's why I got confused. There's no requireLogin tag on homepage, why it keeps looping